# i can not find why the mouseover in this code could not work (javascript)

Tags: javascript

using javascript , i wrote this code that will show images when moving over buttons (image1 , image2 , ... ) it should be done by using mouseover in javascript. here is my code but it doesnt work, can any body solve it? i

```js
        function replaceImg() {
            var img = document.getElementById("first");

            if (img.id === "a") {
                this.src = "images/2.jpg";
            }
            else if (img.id === "b") {
                this.src = "images/2.jpg";
            }
            else if (img.id === "c") {
                this.src = "images/3.jpg";
            }
            else {
                this.src = "images/4.jpg";
            }

        }

        function defaultImg() {
            this.src = "images/7.jpg";
        }
```

```css
<style>
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: blue;
    }

    #first {
        padding-left: 500px;
    }

    #second {
        padding-left: 330px;
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<body> //html code for defining buttons 
    <h1>move your mouse over links for different images</h1>
    <div class='container'>
        <div id="first">
            <button id="a" onMouseOver="replaceImg()" onMouseOut="defaultImg()">
                <p>Image1</p>
            </button>
            <button id="b" onMouseOver="replaceImg()" onMouseOut="defaultImg()">
                <p>Image2</p>
            </button>
            <button id="c" onMouseOver="replaceImg()" onMouseOut="defaultImg()">
                <p>Image3</p>
            </button>
            <button id="d" onMouseOver="replaceImg()" onMouseOut="defaultImg()">
                <p>Image4</p>
            </button>

        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <img id="default" src="images/7.jpg" alt="" width="590" height="350" />

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

i tried different ways also but this is the easiest one

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function replaceImg (obj) {

  var img = document.getElementById("default");

  if (obj.id === "a") {
    img.src = "images/2.jpg";

  } else if (obj.id === "b") {
    img.src = "images/2.jpg";

  } else if (obj.id === "c") {
    img.src = "images/3.jpg";

  }  else {
    img.src = "images/4.jpg";
  }
}

function defaultImg () {
  var img = document.getElementById("default");

  img.src = "images/7.jpg";
}
```

and it needs to be called like

```
<button id="a" onmouseover="replaceImg(this)" onmouseout="defaultImg()">
```

You had the variable `this` with `img` reversed and the `this` value is not available inside the `replaceImg` function.  You have to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you , but i tried your code it is taking only the else statement image while mouseover buttons :/

Answer (score 0):

Html events don't have uppercase(cameltoe syntax) like in javascript:

```js
function replaceImg(){console.log("hey")};
function defaultImg(){console.log("hi")};
```

```html
<p onmouseover="replaceImg()" onmouseout="defaultImg()">hello</p>
```

also you can use your id directly like so if needed :

```
if(a) dosomething();
```

because an id is defined globally and if it's not existing its value is undefined which translates to false(i know it's a bit tricky but in short you just don't need to wrap your id in document.getElementById("myid")  you can just use it as myid.somethingiwanttodo)

also try to put a:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{ /* your javascript code here */ });
```

all around your javascript code to prevent from using html elements that are not yet loaded when you try to use them

which in term gives you something like :

```js
//document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
function writeText(currentElt)
{
  if(currentElt.id=="a1") telement.textContent="hello";
  if(currentElt.id=="a2") telement.textContent="hi";
  if(currentElt.id=="a3") telement.textContent="good day";
  if(currentElt.id=="a4") telement.textContent="how is it";
  if(currentElt.id=="a5") telement.textContent="by";
}
function eraseText(currentElt)
{
  telement.textContent="";
}//});
```

```html
<p id="a1" onmouseover="writeText(this)" onmouseout="eraseText()">a1</p>
<p id="a2" onmouseover="writeText(this)" onmouseout="eraseText()">a2</p>
<p id="a3" onmouseover="writeText(this)" onmouseout="eraseText()">a3</p>
<p id="a4" onmouseover="writeText(this)" onmouseout="eraseText()">a4</p>
<p id="a5" onmouseover="writeText(this)" onmouseout="eraseText()">a5</p>
<p id="telement"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`img.id` it returns the id of the div wish is `first`
it do not returns the id of the images inside the div which is what u want !!